# How do I evaluate LDA gensim model using a set of test documents

Tags: python, gensim, lda

I trained my model using Gensim LDA. Training went okay but the evaluation of model did not go as expected. When I try to evaluate the model using test file in a folder, it outputs the following

<gensim.interfaces.TransformedCorpus object at 0x12bba2b50>

What am I doing wrong? Below is my python code:

```
my_path = "/path/to/files/training folder"
files = os.listdir(my_path)
doc_set = []


for file in files:
    newpath = (os.path.join(my_path, file)) 
    newpath1 = textract.process(newpath)
    newpath2 = newpath1.decode("utf-8")
    doc_set.append(newpath2)

texts = []
for i in doc_set:
    raw = i.lower()
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(raw)
    stopped_tokens = [i for i in tokens if not i in stopwords.words()]
    stemmed_tokens = [p_stemmer.stem(i) for i in stopped_tokens]
texts.append(stemmed_tokens)

dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]


ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=4, random_state=1, id2word = dictionary, passes=60)
print(ldamodel.print_topics(num_topics=4, num_words=25))

#Model evaluation

my_path1 = "/Path/to/file/testing folder"
files1 = os.listdir(my_path1)
doc_set1 = []

for file in files1:
    newpathone = (os.path.join(my_path, file)) 
    newpathtwo = textract.process(newpath)
    newpaththree = newpathtwo.decode("utf-8")
    doc_set1.append(newpaththree)

texts1 = []
for i in doc_set1:
    raw1 = i.lower()
    tokens1 = tokenizer.tokenize(raw1)
    stopped_tokens1 = [i for i in tokens1 if not i in stopwords.words()]
    stemmed_tokens1 = [p_stemmer.stem(i) for i in stopped_tokens1]
    texts1.append(stemmed_tokens1)


dictionary1 = corpora.Dictionary(texts1)
corpus1 = [dictionary1.doc2bow(text) for text in texts1]
print(ldamodel.get_document_topics(corpus1))
```

Comment: What if you print each item in the sequence returned by `ldamodel.get_document_topics(corpus1)`?

Comment: @gojomo I can try. Would you please be able to provide a code for that. Thankyou

Comment: @gojomo I tried this but it didnt work: for i in texts1:
    print(ldamodel.get_document_topics(corpus1))

Comment: That's exactly the same as your existing code. Loop over the results of `ldamodel.get_document_topics(corpus1)`, printing each item, instead. (And why are you passing a full corpus into `get_document_topics()` in the 1st place?)

Comment: @gojomo Dont know how else to do it. I tried looping over the results like this but didnt work:

results = ldamodel.get_document_topics(corpus1)

for each in results:
    print(results)

Comment: In a `for each in results:` loop, you'd want to `print(each)`, **not** `print(results)` (because that's still just the full sequence, not each item).